# Examples of non-compact, holomorphically symplectic Kähler manifolds which are not hyperkähler

Tags: riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-symplectic, hyperkaehler

Let $(M,\omega_{1},I_{1})$ be a non-compact Kähler manifold. If $M$ admits a holomorphic symplectic form $\Omega$, is it possible M not be hyperkähler? Is there any example?

(*)Under the assumption of compactness, I know that $M$ is hyperkähler.

Comment: Since $\Omega$ is a holomorphic (2,0)-form with respect to $I_{1}$, it follows that $\Omega(I_{1}(X),Y) = \sqrt{-1}\Omega(X,Y), \forall X,Y$. Using this and the fact that $\Omega = \omega_{2} + \sqrt{-1}\omega_{3}$, s.t. $\omega_{i} = g(I_{i} \otimes {\rm{id}})$, $i = 2,3$, where $g$ is the K\"{a}ler metric associated to $\omega_{1}$, we can show that $I_{3} = I_{1}I_{2}$.

Comment: From the previous comment, we have that $(g,I_{1},I_{2},I_{3})$ is an almost hyperkähler structure. In the proposition of Joyce's book which I mentioned, the condition $dω_{i} =0$, $\forall i =1,2,3$, implies that $(g,I_{1},I_{2},I_{3})$ is in fact hyperkähler, so we have $\nabla \omega_{i} = 0$, $\forall i = 1,2,3$.

Comment: Why should $I_2$ and $I_3$ be compatible with $g$?

Comment: Sebastian, you are right! The metrics $\omega_{i}({\rm{id}} \otimes I_{i})$, $i=2,3$, might not be equal to $g$. Thanks!